# Xray for JIRA, any working experiences?

Tags: test-management, jira

In my quest for finding the right test management tool, I ended up with [Xray for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xpandit.plugins.xray).
A key requirement was: good integration with Jira.
Xray for Jira didn't pop up by googling around. Somebody recommended it and for sure it looks promising. Beside the reviews at the [jira marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xpandit.plugins.xray), I didn't find many published experiences. Hence my question here...

Answer (score 1):

we are testing Xray for Jira at the moment if it fits our needs. It works quite well. We will have to use the Xporter Extension as well because we want to keep the older versions of tests and the documentation separated from Jira in Confluence. The only bug I came across so far is that it is only possible to a single precondition to a test. It would be more comfortable to have the ability to attach more preconditions. But this can be work-arounded.
Hope this helps! 
Bye, Wolfram

Comment: About the single precondition per test. I think that's because of the Gherkin (Cucumber) integration. One `Feature` can contain multiple `Scenarios` (_Tests_) but only one `Background` (_Precondition_). And it's like that for a reason, I think maintainability is a big driver.

Answer (score 0):

Nick - Xray for JIRA tool is good if you want to get everything paid. If you want to use free then will get very limited feature and also I think will not get real goal for which you want to use tool.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your answer. Our plan is to use the paid version. The pricing is very reasonable compared to other players. I didn't know there is a free version and why would have a different feature set?

Comment: They are providing free trial and paid version. you can get more details at : https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.xpandit.plugins.xray

Comment: A free trial is not exactly a free version isn't it. Anyway I'm interested in working experiences, pros and cons. You don't happen to have any?

Answer (score 0):

We are using XRAY with Jira and its going good.
You can create Test Plans
You can create Test Sets (suites)
You can Create Test Runs/ Test Environments / and Tracebility Matrix and other reports are available in it.

Setup Takes time for the first time but its easy and works well.